# Send json between Python and PHP

Tags: python, php, json, laravel

I have this code in Python (is interesterd poart of the code)

```
elements = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Alex'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jessica'}]
elements_json = json.dumps(elements)
requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/add-element', data = {'json': elements_json})
```

Elements sometimes contain more elements.
In PHP (Laravel) I have this code:

```
public function Store(Request $request) {
    $json = json_decode($request->json );
    echo $json;
}
```

I want to store all elements but for test I want to print that but it not display me empty result. I test that on Postman. Where problem is?

Comment: You created `elements` but you did `json.dumps(partElements)`.  Is that your literal code?

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Comment: You cant `echo` a json_decode return value. use `var_dump($json)`. If you want to decode the json into an array use `json_decode($request->json , true);`. notice the `true` argument

Comment: It return null. I read in Internet that json.dumps doesn't create correctly json and PHP have a problem with decoding that. Look what Python display with json_dumps. Note that I want to store data from json to db. Print that is only for test.

Comment: You read incorrectly.  Python's `json.dumps` is absolutely spec-compliant.  If you echo `$request->json`, do you see your JSON string?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg